# Как сделать плавное изменение скорости анимации через js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В общем нужно сделать так чтобы скорость анимации плавно изменялось. Я не многу понять как сделать так чтобы все было плавно. Как исправить дергание загрузки?

```js
document.body.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {        // скрывает preloader через время
        clearInterval(loadTime);
        document.getElementById('preloader').style.opacity = '0';
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
        }, 1000);
    }, 5000);
    
    var loadSpeed = 1;      // скрость анимации
    
    var loadTime = setInterval(function () {
        var loader = document.getElementsByClassName('load')[0];
        loader.style.animationDuration = loadSpeed + 's';
        loadSpeed -= .2;
    }, 1000)
    
}
```

```css
#preloader{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}

.load{
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: 1s;
    border: 20px solid white;
    border-top-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: load 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes load {
    100%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
        <div class="load"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А нужно ускорять шагом именно раз в секунду? А если на 5 секунд дать интервал раз в 10 миллисекунд. `loadSpeed -= 0.001; }, 10)` — так не видно дергов.

Answer (score 5):

Я таки очень извиняюсь, но не лучше ли воспользоваться возможностями чистого CSS? Есть очень подходящее в данном случае свойство:

```
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 1, 1); // делает анимацию ускоряющейся
```

и еще одно:

```
animation-iteration-count:1; // анимирует один раз
```

В итоге получается гораздо более по феншую:

```js
document.body.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() { // скрывает preloader через время
    document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.load {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 1s;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: load 5s 1 cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 1, 1);
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(1800deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
```

Скрипт нужен только для удаления элемента через время